# Javascript BG Image Change

Tags: javascript, html

My site has a background that looks cool, but might impair usability (and it burns if you look at it too long) so I want a link that changes/removes background image with javascript. I've googled it, but can't find something that works.

Is there a way to make a link like [a href="javascript:???????"]remove bg[/a]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your background image is NOT specified in the body tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var img = document.getElementById('your image ID');
    var shown = true;

    function toggleImg(){
        if(shown == true){
             img.style.display = "none";
             shown = !shown;
        }else{
             img.style.display = "";
             shown = !shown;
        }

    }

</script>
```

**If your background image is specified in the body tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var imgSrc = "your image source"
    var shown = true;

    function toggleImg(){
        if(shown == true){
             document.body.background = "";
             shown = !shown;
        }else{
             document.body.background = imgSrc;
             shown = !shown;
        }

    }
```

```
<a href="javascript:toggleImg();">remove bg</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeBackgroundImage()
{
       document.body.background = "";
}

<a href="#" onclick="removeBackgroundImage();">Change Background</a>
```

Comment: If your background image is specified on the body tag this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't tell us how you put in your background image (ie. the html/css markup) it's difficult to give you an accurate answer.

javascript:var f=eval("document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundImage='inherit';");

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery CSS function.

```
$('#removebg').click(function(){
     $('body').css("backgroundImage","yoururl");
});

<a id="removebg">removebg</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/